# Will not continuing a single player game delete the save game?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

When I open *Ark: Survival Evolved - Mobile* and tap *PLAY ARK* I get asked, whether I want to continue my single player game (refer to the screenshot below). I'd like to check whether the save game is stored in iCloud and if it isn't, move it there in order to continue on another device.

**Would this be possible after selecting *CANCEL* or will the current save game get deleted?**

[image: Continuing a single player game on Ark: Survival Evolved - Mobile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, Tapping *CANCEL* will not delete your save game.** I just took the risk and tried.

You can cancel and then proceed to tap on *MANAGE SAVE DATA*. There you'll see the most **Current Save** game at the top and can store it in either of the 3 local slots or the iCloud slot by tapping *SAVE* next to the respective slot. When you then tap on *PLAY SINGLE PLAYER*, you'll continue with your *Current Save*.

[image]